# MySQL Docker - Check if mysql server is up and running

Tags: mysql, docker, shell, docker-compose, mariadb

I am trying to make an image that uses the MySQL image as its base and I want to create a database (and some other stuff) once I know the server is up. I have a bootstrap script as my entrypoint in which the first thing I do is run mysql image's entrypoint script in background as `./entrypoint.sh mysqld &`.

Currently, what I do after this is start a loop with some sleep that uses `mysqladmin --ping` to check if the server is up. Once its up I start my other commands and start creating the database I want.

This works fine when mysql is already initialized (i.e. not the first time the container is started/entrypoint.sh is executed). But on the first run the image seems to create a temporary mysql server (`mysqld --daemonize --skip-networking --default-time-zone=SYSTEM --socket="${SOCKET}"` - from the entrypoint script), run some commands and then stop that server. Post that it starts the actual server. The problem I am facing is that the mysqladmin ping command actually reacts with a success to the temporary server itself and so my script tries to create the database which fails.

I've read many answers here that say to run the ping command (that I am using) to check if server is up, but none that I saw mention anything about this temporary server or how to detect if it is a temporary one.

Any clues as to how I can detect this ? Or if there is anything better I can do at any part of the flow I have mentioned above ?

I do have one hacky solution in mind right now. One involves updating the entrypoint script to use a different from default socket file for the temporary server, which I can then use to see if the server running is temporary or not, but I'd rather not resort to this if a standard solution exists.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually a Docker container is a wrapper around a single process.  You wouldn't normally try to modify the `mysqld` process to run your application's migrations; in the same way, I'd recommend running an unmodified `mysql` container, and running migrations from a separate container.  You might find waiting for another container to listen for TCP connections to be easier than rewriting `mysql`'s already-involved startup sequence.

Comment: Right. The solution to modify the startup script was my last resort in a sense. But you are right in that I can listen for TCP connections. I didnt realise `--skip-networking` disabled TCP. And abt multiple containers, I want to use this as my "development" container in a way, which is why I'm trying to have just one container to keep it simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the initialization uses the `--skip-networking`, use `--protocol tcp` as an argument to `mysqladmin` to perform the `ping` on tcp, which is when the final instance is running.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked :)
Just read the help for mysqld too. Shld have done that from the start. :) But yes I guess additionally this does explain why the temporary server did not have any ports open either (noticed this sometime after posting the question)

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to danblack's answer for running health checks in docker-compose.yml:

```
healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD","--protocol","tcp"]
```

This will prevent healthy status when running temporary server.