# Connection refused : mariaDB on a webapp running on Jetty on docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, jetty

I have to deploy a web app with a Jetty Server. This app need a database, running on MariaDB. Here the `docker-compose` file used to deploy the app:

```yaml
version: '3.0'

services:

  jetty:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/jetty/Dockerfile
    container_name: app-jetty
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - app
    links:
      - "mariadb:mariadb"

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.7
    container_name: app-mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: myPassword
      MARIADB_DATABASE: APPBD
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - app
  
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: app-adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2002:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge
```

The `Dockerfile` used by the Jetty container:

```
FROM gradle:7.2-jdk17 as grad

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN mkdir src
RUN ls -la
COPY src /tmp/src
COPY build.gradle /tmp/build.gradle
RUN ls -la
RUN gradle --warning-mode all war
RUN ls -la /tmp/build/libs/

FROM jetty:latest
COPY --from=grad /tmp/build/libs/tmp.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT.war
EXPOSE 8080
```

The app is build with Gradle before the initialisation of Jetty.

The problem is the database: it takes several minutes to initialize the MariaDB database. So, when I want to connect to the DB from Adminer, I have to wait until the DB is ready before I can log in. But for my app, I got this: `Could not connect to address=(host=mariadb)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:mariadb, port:3306. Connection refused`, even if the database is ready. I have to stop the `app-jetty` container and restart it to use the database. I thought that `depends_on` will ran the `app-jetty` when the database was ready, but it ran the container when the `app-mariadb` was ran.

I use JDBC to establish connection to the DB : `jdbc:mariadb://mariadb:3306/APPBD?user=root&password=myPassword`. I successfully establish connection on local execution with `gradle appRun` and use `localhost:3306` instead of `mariadb:3306`, so I think I don't have any mistakes on my code.

How can I indicate to the `app-jetty` container to start only when MariaDB is ready?

Comment: Try to figure out the `mariadb` connection on the `jetty` container. For instance, you can do it by `telnet mariadb 3306` to see if the network layer of the compose is working as expected. Generally, there are a lot of things you can do for troubleshooting these kinds of issues.

Comment: I can't use telnet inside `jetty`, got `telnet: command not found`. This is the same for other command such as `wget` or `ping`. With `curl mariadb:3306`, I have `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
'a3y+d:5��-��8Y:U{0w*eATdmysql_native_password!��#08S01Got packets out of order`

Comment: Try a healthcheck like [this example](https://marcopeg.com/docker-compose-healthcheck/) however use `--protocol tcp` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70485527/mysql-docker-check-if-mysql-server-is-up-and-running/70486117?noredirect=1#comment124600307_70486117). "Several minutes" sounds excessive especially without an init.db or custom configuration - could be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose (2.1) supports healthchecks:

Under the mariadb service:

```
    healthcheck:
        test: [ "CMD", "mariadb-admin", "--protocol", "tcp" ,"ping" ]
        timeout: 3m
        interval: 10s
        retries: 10
```

ref: [tip](https://marcopeg.com/docker-compose-healthcheck/).

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I have to use docker-compose version 2.1 instead of 3.0 and add the parameters `-u root -pmyPassword`. The Jetty container takes several minutes to start but it starts and works correctly!

Comment: Odd you needed to downgrade, [healthcheck is in the v3 documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck). Glad its working for you however.