# Prisma in Azure container instances: can't reach database server

Tags: mysql, docker, prisma, sveltekit, azure-container-instances

I have a container group which consists of database(MySQL), client app(SSR, SvelteKit with node-adapter) and reverse proxy(Caddy, for enabling automatic HTTPS)

Dockerfile for database:

```
FROM mysql:8.2.0
COPY init-prod.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
EXPOSE 3306
```

`init-prod.sql` mentioned in the database Dockerfile:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database_name>.* TO '<database_user>'@'%';
-- Required for Prisma Migrate
GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, REFERENCES ON *.* TO '<database_user>'@'%';
-- Flush privileges to apply changes
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Dockerfile for SvelteKit application. The container from which I'm trying to execute `npx prisma migrate deploy` is created from this image.

```
FROM node:18.19.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci --omit dev
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18.19.0
COPY --from=build /app/package.json .
COPY --from=build /app/.env.production .env
COPY --from=build /app/node_modules node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/prisma prisma
COPY --from=build /app/build .
CMD ["npm", "run", "prod"]
```

After successful deployment to Container Instances I'm trying to run migrations with following Azure CLI command:

```
az container exec --resource-group <resource_group> --name <container_group> --container-name app --exec-command "npx --yes prisma migrate deploy"
```

The command output:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MySQL database "txtsummprod" at "db:3306"

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `db`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `db`:`3306`.
```

Prisma `DATABASE_URL` env variable is formed like this:

`mysql://<database_user>:<database_password>@db:3306/<database_name>?connect_timeout=300`

I've tried:

1. adding `?connect_timeout=300` to `DATABASE_URL` [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73919700/10897990)
2. changing node image versions [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73086078/10897990)

But still, no luck. Locally migrations are applied just fine, the problem appears only when I'm attempting to execute `npx prisma migrate deploy` in a container deployed to Container Instances

According to `db` container logs from Azure Container Instances everything seem to be ok and database is ready to accept connections:

```
2024-01-03 22:34:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.2.0-1.el8 started.
2024-01-03 22:34:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-01-03 22:34:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.2.0-1.el8 started.
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock': Operation not supported
2024-01-03T22:34:03.057381Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-01-03T22:34:03.348494Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2024-01-03T22:34:03.377157Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.2.0) starting as process 150
2024-01-03T22:34:03.526733Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000054] [Server] World-writable config file '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' is ignored.
2024-01-03T22:34:03.537967Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010107] [Server] World-writable config file '/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf' has been removed.
2024-01-03T22:34:03.543031Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 328cd822-aa88-11ee-8f84-00155d592a61.
2024-01-03T22:34:03.623222Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-01-03T22:34:10.269749Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-01-03T22:34:11.972853Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-01-03T22:34:11.977611Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-01-03T22:34:12.071977Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2024-01-03T22:34:12.168356Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-01-03T22:34:12.168448Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

YAML for deployment to Azure Container Instances looks like this:

```
apiVersion: 2021-10-01
location: eastus
name: txt-summ
properties:
  containers:
    - name: reverse-proxy
      properties:
        image: summacr.azurecr.io/reverse-proxy:latest
        ports:
          - port: 80
            protocol: TCP
          - port: 443
            protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            memoryInGB: 1.0
            cpu: 1.0
          limits:
            memoryInGB: 1.0
            cpu: 1.0
        volumeMounts:
          - name: proxy-data
            mountPath: /data
          - name: proxy-config
            mountPath: /config
    - name: app
      properties:
        image: summacr.azurecr.io/app:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1.5
            memoryInGB: 1.5
        ports:
          - port: 3000
            protocol: TCP
    - name: db
      properties:
        image: summacr.azurecr.io/db:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1.0
            memoryInGB: 1.0
        volumeMounts:
          - name: db-data
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        environmentVariables:
          - name: MYSQL_USER
            value: $DB_USER
          - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            value: $DB_PASSWORD
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: $DB_NAME
        ports:
          - port: 3306
            protocol: TCP
  ipAddress:
    dnsNameLabel: txt-summ
    ports:
      - port: 80
        protocol: TCP
      - port: 443
        protocol: TCP
    type: Public
  imageRegistryCredentials:
    - server: $ACR_LOGIN_SERVER
      username: $ACR_USERNAME
      password: $ACR_PASSWORD
  volumes:
    - name: proxy-data
      azureFile:
        shareName: $PROXY_DATA_FILE_SHARE_NAME
        storageAccountName: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
        storageAccountKey: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY
    - name: proxy-config
      azureFile:
        shareName: $PROXY_CONFIG_FILE_SHARE_NAME
        storageAccountName: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
        storageAccountKey: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY
    - name: db-data
      azureFile:
        shareName: $DB_DATA_FILE_SHARE_NAME
        storageAccountName: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME
        storageAccountKey: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY
  osType: Linux
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a timing issue: mysql has not started yet before you try to run the migration

Comment: @Shadow is there any way to let app container know whether mysql has started?

Comment: You might need a readiness probe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-readiness-probe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70485527/mysql-docker-check-if-mysql-server-is-up-and-running

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like it wasn't a timing issue but database url issue. While database url

`mysql://<user>:<password>@db:3306/<database>`

works fine locally(given that your database service in docker compose named as `db`) it won't let you to establish database connection in ACI.

Changing `DATABASE_URL` env variable in ACI to

`mysql://<user>:<password>@localhost:3306/<database>`

did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).